# Separate package names for iOS and Android

Tags: nativescript

I currently have a native app published to the App Store and Google Play and both have different package names. I was wanting to know if there is there a way to tell NativeScript to use a one package name for iOS and a different one for Android? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can absolutely do that. For iOS, include a `CFBundleIdentifier` flag in your `app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist` file.

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.mycompany.myapp</string>
```

And for Android, update the `android.defaultConfig.applicationId` in your `app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle` file. See https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world/blob/90b81bcb772ab21a06f06bd502be2043e6afc9ee/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle#L11.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks TJ!

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a solution in 2021, there is an easy way to set it up.

Open your `nativescript.config.ts` and add different `id` properties inside `android` and `ios`:

```
import { NativeScriptConfig } from '@nativescript/core';

export default {
  appPath: 'src',
  appResourcesPath: 'App_Resources',
  android: {
    v8Flags: '--expose_gc',
    markingMode: 'none',
    id: 'com.yourapp.android'
  },
  ios: {
    id: 'com.yourapp.ios'
  }
} as NativeScriptConfig;
```